# Сохранение содержимого div в .doc файл

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть div, содержащий текст, картинки.
Возможно ли сохранить его содержимое в .doc файл.
Смотрел blob, но кроме как сохранить только текст у меня не получилось.

```
function set_description() {

var main_description = $('#description').html();
var images = $('#img').html();
var articul = "<?=$catalogVars['goodsArticle']?>";
var price = "<?=$catalogVars['goodsPrice']?>";
var product_name = "<?=$catalogVars['goodsName']?>";
jQuery.ajax({
      url:'/forma/desc_prdct.php'
      , type:'POST'
      , data:{product_name: product_name, price: price, articul: articul, images:images, main_description: main_description}
      , success: function(response) {
        document.write(response);
     }
  });
```

}
Написал функцию, отправляет все переменные в php скрипт.
Там из переменных формируется html-страница.
Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы скрипт сформировал из разметки .doc и сохранил его у клиента?

Comment: Возможность есть

Comment: на самом деле `.doc` файлы это `zip` архивы с `xml` файлами

Comment: Если вы хоть немного понимаете в PHP, то вам поможет http://phpword.codeplex.com =)